# sFileName contains empty space , DataTable

Tags: jsp, datatables

I am using `jsp` as well as `DataTables` 1.9.4.

I have a weird problem that the file name saved from `DataTables`  contains empty space even though I have no empty space in the title.

```
<title>
   title <!--Here , I only use enter not space-->
</title>
```

The sFileName is using a function to generate so that the file name will contains the system title and suffixed with datetime:

```
 "sFileName": genDownloadFileName(false) 


function genDownloadFileName(isEng){
    return (isEng ? "Download-From-GDAS" : "下载自*") + new Date().Format("yyyy-MM-dd-hhmmss")+".xls"
}
```

but the file name contains space like :
[image]

if I remove the enter and replace the title tag into:
    title

problem will be gone, why? Is it a bug?

Comment: What is `Date().Format()` ?? It is not standard javascript, you must use some kind of library adding functions to Date's prototype ...

Comment: @davidkonrad, this is our written function added to Date's prototype: `Date.prototype.Format = function(fmt)`

Comment: Suspected that, and the error must lie in that function. jQuery dataTables does not add anything to sFileName, and are not using the page title tag to anything, at all.

Comment: @davidkonrad , the sFileName will repace "*" into the title, that's where "title" of the file name comes from and if I remove the empty space of the tag, the empty space from the file name will be gone too